# Mechanism of perf thread binding

Tags: multithreading, pid, sample, perf

I'm confused on the mechanism of perf_event counter binding to children threads of target profiling process.

I'm using [perf_event_open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) to sample CPU CYCLES on the target program. The program would create, let's say 99 threads. The `perf_event_open()` syscall would be invoked only once with the pid of target program(the parent's pid).

Assume all these 100 threads(1 parent + 99 children) are running on 100 different CPUs and sample frequent is set to 99Hz. Question is whether the 99 children threads would be bound to a specific PMU and be sampled just like the parent process automatically. After 1 second's sampling, how many samples we would get and why?

> A. Only 99 samples which from the parent process.

> B. 9900 samples which from all running threads.

> C. others

Answer (score 1):

I've done a tiny experiment with below code, from which I think this question could be answered. The procedure of this experiment would be

1. set signal action, TID and counter reading would be printed in handler
2. bind perf_event_open with the PID of `main()`
3. `pthread_create` another 9 threads in which perform some calculations
4. check the output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>    /* Definition of PERF_* constants */
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h> /* Definition of HW_* constants */
#include <sys/syscall.h>         /* Definition of SYS_* constants */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 1024
#define RANDMAX 1000
#define PRIOR 9
#define SUBSEQUENT 9
#define MAXLEN 2000

struct timespec start, end;
typedef unsigned long long int u64;
std::string counters[MAXLEN];
int idx = 0;

// every SIGPROF would be handled 
void sigHandler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ucontext)
{
    u64 counter;
    read(siginfo->si_fd, &counter, sizeof(counter));

    pid_t tid = gettid();
    //concatenate tid and counter 
    int curr_idx = idx;    
    for(;;){
        if(__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&idx, curr_idx, (curr_idx+1))){
            std::string sample_info = std::to_string(tid) + "::" + std::to_string(counter);
            counters[curr_idx] = sample_info;
            break;
        }
    }    
}

void *multiplyMatrix(void *nothing)
{
    auto A = new double[N][N];
    auto B = new double[N][N];
    auto C = new double[N][N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = (double)rand() / (double)RANDMAX;
            B[i][j] = (double)rand() / (double)RANDMAX;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    pid_t pid;
    pid = gettid();
    int fd;

    //set signal action
    struct sigaction sa, old_sa;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_sigaction = &sigHandler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(SIGPROF, &sa, &old_sa);

    //config perf_event attr
    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(pe));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
    pe.size = sizeof(pe);
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.sample_freq = 10; // sample mode with 10Hz
    pe.freq = 1;
    pe.wakeup_events = 1;
    pe.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN;

    //open perf_event binding with main() pid
    if ((fd = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pe, pid, -1, -1, 0)) < 0)
    {
    };

    //fd control and io control
    struct f_owner_ex ex = {
        .type = F_OWNER_PID,
        .pid = pid,
    };
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETSIG, SIGPROF) < 0 || fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN_EX, &ex) < 0 || fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | FASYNC | O_ASYNC) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "fcntl error" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0) < 0 || ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "ioctl error" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "pid = "<< pid <<std::endl;

    // 9 pthreads would be created
    pthread_t sub_threads[SUBSEQUENT];
    int ret = 0;
    void *retval = NULL;

    std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    for (int i = 0; i < SUBSEQUENT; i++)
    {
        ret = pthread_create(&sub_threads[i], NULL, &multiplyMatrix, NULL);
        if (ret != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error happens on pthread creating" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SUBSEQUENT; i++)
    {
        ret = pthread_join(sub_threads[i], &retval);
        if (ret != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error happens on pthread joining" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;

    double tdiff = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + 1e-9 * (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
    
    std::cout << "time used: " << std::to_string(tdiff) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Start to print counter" << std::endl;

    //output the pid info and corresponding counter
    // std::cout << std::to_string(counters.size())<< std::endl;
    // for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = counters.begin(); it != counters.end(); it++){
    //     std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
    // }
    // std::cout << std::to_string(counters.size())<< std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < idx; i++){
        std::cout<<counters[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This experiments have been performed dozens of times and all of them presented the same result.Below is the output from one run.

```
pid = 2832444
start
end
time used: 11.872525
Start to print counter
2832444::22222
2832444::191758
2832444::200708
2832444::220478
2832444::236749
2832444::321106
```

Looks like the only thread that would be sampled by perf and trigger SIGPROF is the PID of main().

But I'm not sure about this conclusion. If some one has the correct answer, please share with me.